# Lower bound for the size of a determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Given a matrix $A$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and let
$a_{\min} = \min_{\substack{1 \leq i \leq n \\ 1 \leq j \leq n}} \{ |A_{ij}| \}$. Does 
$$
a_{\min} \leq \det(A)
$$
always hold?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Consider the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} \epsilon & 0 \\ 0 & \epsilon \end{pmatrix}$. (This works only if you ignore zero entries, see user1551's comment.)

Another hint (following Famous Blue Raincoat's comment): Consider the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Your first example doesn't violate the inequality, as $a_\min=0\le\epsilon^2=\det(A)$.